# Inductive Proof for $\sum_{ i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

So I'm supposed to prove 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}=1-\frac{1}{2^n} \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$$
via Inductive Proof. (Although I'm English, I'm studying in German so sorry if my terms are a bit off)

What I've done:

1. Proved the statement is true for n=0.
2. Showed I need to prove 
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^i}=1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
3. Then:
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=^{!}1-\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

From there I come no further. Have I made a mistake in the induction process or is there a way to simplify my result that I'm not seeing so that the induction works?

Thanks!

Andy

Comment: Since your sum starts with $i=1$ the first step of induction is to prove it is true for $n=1$ and not $0$

Comment: Although the sum starts with i=1, it must be proved for all n \in \mathbb{N}.  We include zero in the natural numbers here..

Comment: But then what does $\sum_{i=1}^0$ mean?

Comment: If the index is larger than n the result is (per definition) zero. The result is fairly trivial but still part of the inductive process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made no mistake.
$$
1-\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=1-\frac{2}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
$$
Therefore by induction, given identity holds for all $n$.

Comment: Wow! That was fast! But I'm afraid I don't understand the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ to $\frac{2}{2^{n+1}}$. Is multiplied by $\frac{2}{2}$?

Comment: Ah.. yes ok, I see. Thanks! Typical of me that I understand the concepts but have problems with the algebra

Comment: Giving the acceptance because you were first. Thanks for all the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following 
\begin{align}
1-\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=1-(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})
=1-(\frac{2}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})=1-\frac{2-1}{2^{n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

What you got is equal to:

$$1-\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}-\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)=1-\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}.$$